# Laravel Request data when submitting a form is lost when running our project in IIS, what are the possible causes?

Tags: php, laravel, iis

I am working in a Laravel project running in IIS that, in some cases, submits a lot of form data. When that happens, I end up with a TokenMismatchException. When running the project through php artisan serve, it works fine regardless of how many form elements are submitted.

I have also modified the values of max_input_vars and max_input_nesting_level in php.ini but it still does not work in IIS.

Comment: It could be due to PHP version requirement not fulfilled, PHP Extension requirement not fulfilled. Check the IIS log as well.

Comment: Check the IIS configuration for maximum upload size (not sure how it would be called) or something similar